# Distinguish timeout from user cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

`HttpClient` has a builtin timeout feature (despite being all asynchronous, i.e. timeouts could be considered orthogonal to the http request functionality and thus be handled by generic asynchronous utilities, but that aside) and when the timeout kicks in, it'll throw a `TaskCanceledException` (wrapped in an `AggregateException`).

The TCE contains a `CancellationToken` that equals `CancellationToken.None`.

Now if I provide `HttpClient` with a `CancellationToken` of my own and use that to cancel the operation before it finishes (or times out), I get the exact same `TaskCanceledException`, again with a `CancellationToken.None`.

Is there still a way, **by looking only at the exception thrown**, to figure out whether a timeout canceled the request, without having to make my own `CancellationToken` accessible to the code that checks the exception?

P.S. Could this be a bug and `CancellationToken` got somehow wrongly fixed to `CancellationToken.None`? In the *cancelled using custom CancellationToken* case, I'd expect `TaskCanceledException.CancellationToken` to equal that custom token.

**Edit** 
To make the problem a bit more clear, with access to the original `CancellationTokenSource`, it is easy to distinguish timeout and user cancellation:

> origCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested == **true**

Getting the `CancellationToken` from the exception though gives the wrong answer:

> ((TaskCanceledException) e.InnerException).CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == **false**

Here **a minimal example**, due to popular demand:

```
public void foo()
{
    makeRequest().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        try
        {
            var result = task.Result;
            // do something with the result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TaskCanceledException innerException = e.InnerException as TaskCanceledException;
            bool timedOut = innerException != null && innerException.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false;

            // Unfortunately, the above .IsCancellationRequested
            // is always false, no matter if the request was
            // cancelled using CancellationTaskSource.Cancel()
            // or if it timed out
        }
    });
}

public Task<HttpResponseMessage> makeRequest()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url");

    passCancellationTokenToOtherPartOfTheCode(cts);
    return client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, cts.Token);
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal piece of code that exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: why isn't the code that starts the task handling the exception? That piece of code should already have the CancellationToken, it could manage that scenario and then just throw the exception that you want your higher level try/catch block to receive, without the TokenSource

Comment: @FranciscoNoriega Sometimes you want to separate code, e.g. to make it reusable, and also in asynchronously executed code. So you end up catching exceptions in different places than where the code executed is defined. I don't want to have to pass all state that is involved around, especially as the exception seems to provide that state when it is needed - except it does not work like I'd think it's supposed to. Have a look at the stripped down example that roughly shows how I use it.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy, have you managed to workaround the problem? I'm in a similar situation, I have an app where the most of exception handling is done in one place.

Comment: @ArthurNunes What you could do is create your own `MyTaskCanceledException` with a flag. You then catch the original `TaskCanceledException` in a scope where you have access to the original `CancellationTokenSource` and repackage it into your own exception, setting the flag using `origCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested`.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy, in the end I did that, but I throw TimeoutException instead. The problem with that approach is that I have to do this every time I use HttpClient, or create my own extension methods.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is certainly how this *should* work in theory, but unfortunately in practice `IsCancellationRequested` does not (reliably) get set on the token that is attached to the exception:

[Cancelling an HttpClient Request - Why is TaskCanceledException.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29319086/62600)

Comment: you may not be able to use the attached token, but if you have the original token (that was passed to `SendAsync`), you can use that. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I see, I'm missing that the question required relying only on the exception data.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they both return the same exception (possibly because of timeout internally using a token too) but it can be easily figured out by doing this:

```
   catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return -1;
                }

                return -2;
            }
```

so basically if you hit the exception but your token is not cancelled, well it was a regular http timeout

Comment: I made **by looking only at the exception thrown** in my question bold and added a bit more specifics to make it more clear what I'm asking.

Comment: `OperationCanceledException` is also thrown if the `HttpClient` is disposed of while the request is pending, or if `HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests` is called. These cases can be distinguished if you control the calls to these methods.

Comment: this answer lacks details... where does `token` come from? is it a property of the exception? downvoting until you improve it

Comment: @ympostor  that information is there in the original question. He is providing his own token, that's where it comes from.