# How can a default(CancellationToken) have a corresponding CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, .net, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

When I create a default `CancellationToken` I can see in the debugger that the `CancellationToken` has a `CancellationTokenSource` associated with it which is stored in the private `m_source` field:

[image: Not null]

I am wondering how can that be as for structs the `default` keyword [*"will return each member of the struct initialized to zero or null depending on whether they are value or reference types"*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) and `CancellationTokenSource` is a reference type.

`CancellationToken` does have 2 constructors that set this field however they are irrelevant as `default(CancellationToken)` doesn't call constructors and `new CancellationToken()` (which has the exact same behavior) doesn't call a constructor becuase structs can't have parameterless constructors ([yet](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/562559)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`default(CancellationToken)` does create a `CancellationToken` where `m_source` is `null`. You can see that by getting the value of that private field using reflection:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof (CancellationToken).
    GetField("m_source", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).
    GetValue(default(CancellationToken)) ?? "null");
```

Output:

```
null
```

You can also see that by pining only the relevant field in the debugger:

[image: null]

So, what happens?

The debugger, in order to display the contents of the `CancellationToken`, accesses its properties one by one. When the inner `CancellationTokenSource` is `null` the `WaitHandle` property creates and sets a default `CancellationTokenSource` before delegating to its `WaitHandle` property:

```
public WaitHandle WaitHandle
{
    get
    {
        if (m_source == null)
        {
             m_source = CancellationTokenSource.InternalGetStaticSource(false);
        }

        return m_source.WaitHandle;
    }
}
```

In conclusion, `default(CancellationToken)` and `new CancellationToken` create an empty struct where `m_source` is `null` but [by looking at the struct in the debugger you are filling that field](http://www.americanthinker.com/legacy_assets/articles/assets/White.png) with a default `CancellationTokenSource` instance that can't be cancelled.