# F# async and TPL task cancellation

Tags: asynchronous, f#, task-parallel-library

I am looking into a problem where a chain of method calls between various C# async methods and F# async functions is hanging a program. I think the F# script below reproduces the same problem by mixing F# async and TPL:

```
open System
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

let testy = async {
    let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    Task.Run(fun () ->
        printfn "Inside first task"
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        printfn "First task now cancelling the second task"
        tokenSource.Cancel()) |> ignore

    let! result =
        Task.Factory.StartNew<int>((fun () ->
            printfn "Inside second task"
            Thread.Sleep(2000)
            printfn "Second task about to throw task cancelled exception"
            tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
            printfn "This is never reached, as expected"
            0),
            tokenSource.Token)
        |> Async.AwaitTask

    return result }

printfn "Starting"
let result = testy |> Async.StartAsTask |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
printfn "Program ended with result: %d" result
```

Running this program in FSI hangs the interpreter. I get the following output before it hangs:

```
Starting
Inside first task
Inside second task
First task now cancelling the second task
Second task about to throw task cancelled exception
```

I've discovered that if I change the line

```
let result = testy |> Async.StartAsTask |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

to

```
let result = testy |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

then it no longer hangs and "OperationCanceledException" is shown in the FSI as expected, but I don't know why.

Comment: What's the output from tracing statements?

Comment: I've added the printfn output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cancellation token is being passed to `Task.Factory.StartNew`.  So when it's canceled `Async.StartAsTask` will never start and always report a status of `WaitingForActivation`.  If the token isn't passed to `Task.Factory.StartNew` then the status will change to 'Faulted' which will unblock `Async.AwaitTask` which will allow `Async.RunSynchronously` to rethrow the exception.

To fix

```
let result = testy |> Async.StartAsTask |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The same cancellation token needs to be passed to `Async.StartAsTask`.

```
let result = 
    Async.StartAsTask (testy, TaskCreationOptions.None, tokenSource.Token) 
    |> Async.AwaitTask 
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately in the real code the task cancellation is caused by an HttpClient timeout, and in that case passing the cancellation token to both HttpClient.SendAsync and Async.StartAsTask doesn't fix the issue. I wonder whether maybe this is due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319086/cancelling-an-httpclient-request-why-is-taskcanceledexception-cancellationtoke, it sounds like HttpClient does weird stuff with cancellation tokens