# How to detect if HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests was used to cancel pending requests?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, dotnet-httpclient, cancellation, request-cancelling

**Application Setup**

---

1. I am using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to make mulitple Async POST requests to a REST service from a Windows Forms Application.
2. Meanwhile the response is fetched from the REST service the application shows a **Processing...** window with a **Cancel** button.
3. Now, when the user presses the **Cancel** button I am using [HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.net.http.httpclient.cancelpendingrequests%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to cancel the ongoing requests.
4. Using [HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.net.http.httpclient.cancelpendingrequests%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) throws [TaskCanceledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the [PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138190%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) mthod call.

---

**Query**

1. Is there any way I detect that the [TaskCanceledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was thrown due the calling of [HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.net.http.httpclient.cancelpendingrequests%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and not due to any other reason (like timeout)
2. Is there any other approach to achieve similar cancellation functionality?

Thanks

---

Answer (score 3):

Catch the exception and check the `TaskCanceledException.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` property. If true, you can be fairly certain that it was an explicitly requested cancellation vs. a timeout.

Having said that, be cautious with this solution and do some testing. As I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319086/cancelling-an-httpclient-request-why-is-taskcanceledexception-cancellationtoke) a while back, there are cases where you would think that bit should be set and it is not.

Comment: I do not believe that this is correct.  CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested simple looks at CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequsted.