# Return context data from time of request with response in Typescript async http call

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I have this async method inside an Angular service:

```
public async getListings() {

    // generate path, body, headers

    return await this.http.post<any>(path, body, headers)
    .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
    ).toPromise()
}
```

I have this setup in an Angular component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.loadThree();

    var self = this;
    setInterval(function () {
        if ((self.container.scrollHeight - (self.scrollWindow.scrollTop + self.scrollWindow.clientHeight) < 1000) {
            if (!self.loading) {
                self.loading = true;
                self.getPages()
                self.loading = false;
            }
        }
    }, 1000)
}

public async loadThree() {
    this.loading = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
      await this.getPages()
    }
    this.loading = false;
}

public async getPages() {
    // ....
    var postResponse = await this.<servicename>.getListings();
    // ...
}
```

The idea is that I generate 3 pages when the site loads, then register an interval to check if the user has scrolled within 1000px of the bottom of the div. If he has, I make the next API call to pull another page.

If the user does a search for new parameters, I clear the results, but it's possible I have already made a request to load a page for old parameters, and those will then be added to the results from the new parameters when the API returns. I'm looking for a way to check if the request is old, so I can ignore the results in the component.

Comment: "_requests are made multiple times in a row_" - please show how this is achieved. In other words, show how the `getListings()` function is called.

Comment: @MichaelD, added. Hope it's more clear.

Comment: The HttpClient has the concept of CancellationTokens. Maybe that would be of some help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319086/cancelling-an-httpclient-request-why-is-taskcanceledexception-cancellationtoke

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna be brave and code this off the top of my head:

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash-es'

interface IPayload {
  path: string,
  body: any,
  headers: any
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MissionService {

  private prevPayload: IPayload

  // Observable sources
  private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<IPayload>();

  // Observable streams
  missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable().pipe(
    // switchMap here will auto abort old requests if the request has not completed by the time a new request is made
    // you can see the aborts in network tab devtools
    distinctUntilChanged((prev: IPayload, curr: IPayload) => isEqual(prev, curr),
    switchMap((payload: IPayload) => {
      return this.http.post<any>(payload.path, payload.body, payload.headers).pipe(
        catchError(() => of(null))
      )
    })
  );

  // call this to make new HTTP request
  makeNewRequest(path: string, body: any, headers: any) {
    const payload: IPayload = {path, body, headers}
    this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(payload)
  }
}
```

Then in your component subscribe as follows:

```
constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.missionService.missionAnnounced$.subscribe((upToDateStuff: any) => {
     if (upToDateStuff != null) {
       console.log( upToDateStuff )
     } else {
       console.log( 'something went wrong' )
     }        
  })
}
```

Comment: Just spitballing here, but this may be a good use of BehaviorSubject as well? Could reset to null when you want to cancel, etc.

Comment: So I've tested your change and I'm getting it to make requests. However the thing I'm seeing is that it is aborting any* request that has not returned by the time the next is made. I need it to only abort if the IPayload (search params) has been changed since it was called. Not sure if that is even achievable. Let me know if I've missed something, thanks for your input!

Comment: I've made changes - distinctUntilChanged should prevent this firing unless the payload has changed - e.g. if a 2nd request has the same payload as the previous it should be ignored altogether (should not even make the request) - To simplify checking for equality I've introduced lodash isEqual - however, you could write you own equality check to check if the previous payload is equal or not if you dont want to use lodash (using lodash here just keeps the code clean and easier to read, you dont have to actually use it)

Comment: BTW if you do not want it to abort the previous request if it is still in progress then just use mergeMap instead of switchMap

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in adapting how I was doing the call.
I stopped returning the promise from the service, and instead return the observable:

```
public getListings() {

    // generate path, body, headers

    return this.http.post<any>(path, body, headers)
    .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}
```

Then in the component, I subscribe to it:

```
public serviceSub: Subscription;

public getPages() {
     this.serviceSub = this.<serviceName>.getListings()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data)
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error)
          }
        )
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Problem happened")
    }
}
```

That way, when my user runs another search with new params I can forget any request that was made before he searched by, as he hits search, calling unsubscribe:

```
this.serviceSub.unsubscribe();
```

Any input is welcome, thanks!

Comment: This works and is simpler. However, this will lead to duplicate requests being made unnecessarily, thus putting an extra unnecessary load on your server. Probably not your biggest concern ;)