# Why check the cancelationToken when evaluating OperationCanceledException?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric, cancellation, cancellation-token

An OperationCanceledException could be thrown in a couple of different reasons:

- The cancelation token has been set, or
- There has been a timeout (TaskCancelationException)

To get around this, a common workaround (described here, et al: [Distinguish timeout from user cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666922/distinguish-timeout-from-user-cancellation)) is as follows:

```
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return -2;
}
```

But it would make more sense for me to look at the actual cancelation state that was given to the exception. Something like this:

```
if (ex is OperationCanceledException ocEx)
{
    if (ocEx.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return -2;
}
```

Am I missing something, is there some reason this is not promoted as a solution for this common problem?

Comment: I've always used `ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`. That's the standard way, AFAIK. In many (if not most) cases, you don't even have access to the original `token` variable inside the `catch` block.

Comment: The cancellation might be caused by a nested token - so it really depends on the correct semantics. *Checking the `IsCancellationRequested` of token passed to the OCE is a bit silly, however, as the OCE says "this is the token that caused me, thus it's cancelled".* One might want to check the OCE token against the KNOWN token to ensure it was thrown by the known: `if (one.CancellationToken == myCancellationToken)` - not checking to see "if cancelled" here (as the OCE token *is* cancelled if it was triggered by a CT), rather if it's the same trigger token. Anyway, semantics..

Comment: (Hint: if there is an internal CT causing the OCE that is not chained from the known token then the cancellation state is not directly tied to the known `token`; hence first semantics. Even if it is linked, the linked token may be cancelled independently without trigger cancellation of the linked sources eg.)

Comment: @user2864740 I didn't pay attention to the part about the timeout in the question. Your logic actually makes sense when dealing with nested tokens or if one wants to distinguish between a timeout and a cancellation request. That being said, I'm 100% sure that I've encountered situations where an OCE is thrown but no cancellation was involved whatsoever and that's when `ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` becomes relevant.

Comment: @Hoppy If you're trying to distinguish between a timeout and a cancellation request, please note that my first comment doesn't apply to this situation because `ocEx.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` will return true in both cases (did you try it?) while `token.IsCancellationRequested` will only return true in the case of a cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (ex is OperationCanceledException ocEx)
> {
>    if (ocEx.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
>    {
>        return -1;
>    }
>
>    return -2;
> }
> ```

The `ocEx.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` will be `true` 99% of the time, so if you do this, your method will return `-1` 99% of the time. The reason for checking the `token.IsCancellationRequested` is because you want to differentiate between:

1. The `OperationCanceledException` was caused by the cancellation of the known `token`.
2. The `OperationCanceledException` has some other cause.

You can't really be 100% sure that your `token` caused the exception, because there is a race condition: the exception might occur before the cancellation of the `token`, and then the `token` was canceled shortly before checking the `token.IsCancellationRequested`. But this race condition is subtle and not very important, and you can't do anything about it anyway.